# MySQL - possible to show replication lag from timestamp in the past?

Tags: mysql, sql

We have graphs that indicate replication lag occurred during a timestamp from a few days ago. The replication lag is now normalized, but we would like to see what the exact value was at that timestamp.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean "during a timestamp"?

Comment: No, this is not possible. Graphs you have most likely measure lag at that particular momentum and store it somewhere (what's your graphing engine?) - so the only way to get that value is to ask your graphing backend. Depending on its data granularity you might or might not get an exact result.

Comment: maybe it has nothing to do with any value. An indescribable anomaly.

Comment: Ok, good to know. Thanks guys

Comment: I have no idea what your question is really asking.  Please provide the tables structure, sample data, and indicate what you want a query to return.

Answer (score 0):

You need to periodically execute “show slave status” query on a slave instance to get the details of the slave and extract "Seconds_Behind_Master" metric using regular expression. You can store the output according to the timestamps and have a look at it later.

If you want to display the output of Replication lag on a User Interface then you can use a tool called [SeaLion](https://sealion.com) which stores the raw output of commands and displays it graphically as well. It has a custom parsing framework implemented as well to extract values using a python script.